# Does Object.setPrototypeOf set prototype of another object or set chain?

Tags: javascript

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

> The **`Object.setPrototypeOf()`** static method sets the prototype (i.e., the internal `[[Prototype]]` property) of a specified object to another object or `null`.

By this statement what I understand is it sets (replace) Shape.prototype as prototype of Rectangle constructor function. If that's the case then why is Rectangle constructor function still able to access area method because I already set Shape.prototype for  Rectangle's prototype. I assume it is creating chain instead  of replacing prototype of Rectangle.

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function(l, b) {
    return l * b;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Rectangle.prototype, Shape.prototype);

Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;


console.log(Rectangle.prototype)

const r = new Rectangle();
console.log(r.area(5, 4))
```

Comment: You are settings the prototype of constructor functions here, not the objects that were generated. MDN is referring to changing the prototype of an instance, so `setPrototypeOf( new Rectangle, Shape.prototype )`. Changing the prototype of the constructor function just changes it's `Function` prototype I think, not the prototype of an instance of it.

Comment: ok i am not getting your answer. "Changing the prototype of the constructor function just changes it's Function prototype I think, not the prototype of an instance of it".  Do you mean prototype for constructor function and prototype for instance of that construcotor function are different?

Comment: What I mean is that from what I can read at MDN, this method is meant to change the prototype of an instanced object, not the prototype of a constructor object. That _is_ different I think. It gets very confusing fast with all the mentions of prototype, but the example sets the prototype of `{}` and not `function foo(){};` or something.

Comment: "*It sets (replace) Shape.prototype as prototype of Rectangle constructor function.*" - no?! It sets `Shape.prototype` as prototype of `Rectangle.prototype`. Not sure where you got the constructor function from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By this statement what I understand is it sets (replace)
> Shape.prototype as prototype of Rectangle constructor function

No, that is not what's happening here, it's **not** doing:

```
Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype
```

but instead, it's more akin to doing:

```
Rectangle.prototype.[[Prototype]] = Shape.prototype
```

where *[[Prototype]]* here is an internal slot on the `Rectangle.prototype` object<sup>1</sup>.

The *[[Prototype]]* slot on an object refers to what that object "inherits" from - when you access a property on an object, JavaScript will first for that property on the current object itself, and if it's not found, the object in stored in the *[[Prototype]]* slot is searched. If it's not found there either, that object's *[[Prototype]]* is searched and so on until it is either found or no objects are left in the *[[Prototype]]* chain (we hit `null`). It is the *[[Prototype]]* slot that stores the information to create an object's "prototype chain" by linking to the "parent" objects.

So what is this line doing?:

```js
Object.setPrototypeOf(Rectangle.prototype, Shape.prototype);
```

This sets the *[[Prototype]]* chain to allow `Rectangle` to inherit the methods and properties added to `Shape.prototype`. When you create an instance of your `Rectangle` with `new Rectangle()`, you create a new object, which has a *[[Prototype]]* slot set to the object `Rectangle.prototype`, which in turn now has a *[[Prototype]]* slot set to `Shape.prototype` thanks to the `.setPrototypeOf()` call, allowing you to also access methods defined on there such as `move()`:

```js
new Rectangle() -- [[Prototype]] --> Rectangle.prototype --> [[Prototype]] --> Shape.prototype -- [[Prototype]] --> Object.prototype --> [[Prototype]] --> null
```

In this case, when you do `r.area()`, the `area` property is first searched on the instance itself, `r`. Since it's not there, JavaScript will check if the object stored in the *[[Prototype]]* of `r` has it, which is `Rectangle.prototype`. In this case, `area` does exist on `Rectangle.prototype` and so the search stops, and that's what's used.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Note that accessing/setting `[[Prototype]]` like this in JavaScript isn't valid JavaScript, as internal slots cannot be accessed directly like this via JS code. Instead, we need to use methods such as `setPrototypeOf()` to indirectly interact with them and to perform certain checks before setting them.

Comment: "*the `Rectangle`'s constructor function's prototype object*" - that sounds like you're referring to `Rectangle.[[prototype]]`. To avoid any ambiguity, I recommend to always write either `.prototype` (property) or *[[prototype]]* (chain link).